# Custom slider on css: problems with checked property

Tags: html, css

I want to make custom slider on css. Here is its code:

```css
.slider input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.slider__slider-controls {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider__slider-controls label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background-color: #bec2c7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-slider__one:checked ~ .radio-slider-1 {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: @white;
}

.radio-slider__two:checked ~ .radio-slider-2 {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: @white;
}

.radio-slider__three:checked ~ .radio-slider-3 {
border: 3px solid #000000;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: @white;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
          <input type="radio" id="radio-slider-1" class="radio-slider radio-slider__one" checked>
          <input type="radio" id="radio-slider-2" class="radio-slider radio-slider__two">
          <input type="radio" id="radio-slider-3" class="radio-slider radio-slider__three">
          <div class="slider__slider-controls">
            <label for="radio-slider-1" class="radio-slider-1"></label>
            <label for="radio-slider-2" class="radio-slider-2"></label>
            <label for="radio-slider-3" class="radio-slider-3"></label>
          </div>
```

If I understand this property right it will make action on .radio-slider-1 only when .radio-slider__one in checked state. But it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here.

`.radio-slider__three:checked ~ .radio-slider-3` is saying:

When `.radio-slider__three` is checked, find a sibling of class `.radio-slider-3` and apply these styles. In your html `.radio-slider-3` is not a sibling, but rather a child of a sibling. So to fix this you should change the selectors to be `.radio-slider__one:checked ~ .slider__slider-controls .radio-slider-1`

The next thing is that your radio elements have no `name` attribute, so when you "check" one you can uncheck it because you aren't selecting a different option. If you give them the same name attribute (`slider` in my example) they will only have 1 selected at a time.

```css
.slider input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.slider__slider-controls {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider__slider-controls label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background-color: #bec2c7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-slider__one:checked ~ .slider__slider-controls .radio-slider-1 {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: white;
}

.radio-slider__two:checked ~ .slider__slider-controls .radio-slider-2 {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: white;
}

.radio-slider__three:checked ~ .slider__slider-controls .radio-slider-3 {
border: 3px solid #000000;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
          <input name="slider" type="radio" id="radio-slider-1" class="radio-slider radio-slider__one" checked>
          <input name="slider" type="radio" id="radio-slider-2" class="radio-slider radio-slider__two">
          <input name="slider" type="radio" id="radio-slider-3" class="radio-slider radio-slider__three">
          <div class="slider__slider-controls">
            <label for="radio-slider-1" class="radio-slider-1"></label>
            <label for="radio-slider-2" class="radio-slider-2"></label>
            <label for="radio-slider-3" class="radio-slider-3"></label>
          </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56fz4s1u/)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is wrong for the `~` selector. For `A ~ B`, it finds `B` matches following `A` at the same current level, not descendants.

Pull your labels out of the `<div>`, or add the div just after the `~` so it becomes part of the "following sibling" selection.

`.radio-slider__one:checked ~ .slider__slider-controls > .radio-slider-1`